# Wordpress Theme Footer Social Share link issue

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, footer

I'm a user of an exist wordpress "Disco" theme, based on this to modify my website. but right now I have met some problems need your help.

There has a "share social links" part at each bottom of page(footer space), it looks like built-in? I don't know. And there also has no "Widget" and "menu" section in my "Appearance" section.

I also installed the WPCode plugin, if use custom code to move this share links at footer space, what should I add in the WPCode's "Code Snippets" footer part?

How can I remove it from each page footer?

Please see the screenshot link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-Jk78LT7hSOovvG_JkYIZ-TXPRlk457/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JMoeKGz4a7eVBCwxtEYjM4P4C3XnYj7u/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much, look forward,

Comment: Can you share your website link?

Comment: Hi Earid, thanks for response, sorry I'm totally a newbie, the website is not public yet, so how can I share the website link? thanks.

Comment: I'm modify based on this theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/disco/ . in this theme demo there hasn't nay "share social links", but when download the theme, it displayed at each page footer space.

Comment: I added a solution, check if it works, otherwise site URL needed to check the code.

Answer (score 0):

add this css code on customizer

```
div#jp-post-flair {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer.